# Positioning node in the top middle of the screen in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a simple game for iOS using SpriteKit. However I have one problem that I need  help figuring out. In my game I have three buttons that do certain things in my game, However I'm having trouble positioning my nodes to appear along the the top middle of the screen. I've tried several combinations of code but no luck. I was wondering if anyone knew what I did wrong and could help me fix it. I have posted my function below along with a screenshot of what it currently looks like. Thanks

[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3bn62_z-uzZTmJRVnJKcDdIazA/view?usp=sharing)

```
func createButtons()
{
    buttonOne.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width / 8.5, y:self.size.height)
    buttonTwo.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width, y:self.size.height)
    buttonThree.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 7, y: self.size.height)
    self.addChild(buttonOne)
    self.addChild(buttonTwo)
    self.addChild(buttonThree)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sprite kit, Coordinate system is Cartesian. The (0,0) point is on the left bottom,and the position means the center point of node.